# Citing a Youtube video in New Hart's Rules style?

Tags: publications, citations

I'm preparing a paper for publication with Taylor & Francis Group. The journal follows the **TF no. 1** style but there is no mention on how to cite a source such an online video. Rather, at the end of the style guide they say to refer to **New Hart's Rules** for usage that is not specified in the guide or uncertain. However, New Hart's Rules seems to refer to **Butcher’s Copy - editing 10.6**. So, I'm rather confused on how to cite such a source.

The citation in APA Style would be as follows:

> Sesame Workshop. (Producer) (2010). Sesame Street. Journey to Ernie: Beach [Web]. Retrieved from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnRnxkX2U2U&feature=plcp

Does anyone know how should be adjusted to meet *Taylor & Francis no. 1 / New Hart's Rules / Butcher’s Copy - editing 10.6* style?

Comment: I believe the answer can be found in the [_New Hart's Rules_](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0198610416/ref=rdr_ext_tmb) themselves. (Look at Amazon's preview starting at around p. 350.) A video on the Web can probably be cited as a Web resource, rather than as a video resource.

Answer (score 4):

I would take your best shot at getting the citation style correct and then let the copy editor deal with it. I cannot imagine a manuscript being rejected because someone used the wrong citation style for an "esoteric" entry type. Part of taking your best shot would be to scan the reference lists of the past few issues or a through electronic search for someone else who has cited a youtube video.